# Eclipse Android App errors on creation

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use eclipse to make an Android app. However, when it finished making the files, it came with a bunch of errors that I don't know how to fix. I'm afraid to use the quick fixes, as in the past they usually break everything and the code doesn't work.

```
The import android.support cannot be resolved   MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 3  Java Problem

ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 9  Java Problem

ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 33 Java Problem

The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MyActivity must override or implement a supertype method MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 25 Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 30 Java Problem

The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MyActivity   MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 20 Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 20 Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 14 Java Problem

The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MyActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 18 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MyActivity must override or implement a supertype method    MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 12 Java Problem

ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MyActivity.java /MinerMadness/src/com/cosmicluck/minermadness   line 13 Java Problem
```

Thank you, hopefully I can get this resolved so I can actually start coding!

Comment: you need appcompat library. import it or use android studio.

Comment: I imported it I believe, and it didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest support library

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Yes, I did that but it didn't fix the errors even after I restarted eclipse